# IBM Domino server replicating from absolute path

Tags: replication, lotus-domino, lotus

I have two Domino servers which do a lot of replication, most of which is normal, but once in a while, changes get lost.  I suspect it's a replication issue, but still haven't found the problem.  One anomalous thing I found is that periodically in the log of Srv1/Acme, I see:

```
04/14/2021 12:38:21 PM  Pulling D:\IBM\Domino\data\consumer\worksheet.nsf from Srv2/Acme Consumer\Worksheet.nsf
```

I have no connection documents that specify an absolute path, and other replication events between the same servers and database use a relative path.  I could not find any agents that had the absolute path either.  I did a text search (like you would search an ordinary text file) of all the NSFs that might be related, and found 1 occurrence in worksheet.nsf, but when I search using the All Documents view (which literally as all the documents in the database), the string is not found.  The question is then, I know the string is somewhere in the 6GB of .nsf, how can I find the document or design element that has it?

UPDATE: I found the agent where it's happening, but I still don't know why. Here's the snippet of code:

```
Set s = New NotesSession 
Set db=s.Currentdatabase
Set view=db.getview("Configuration")
Set ConfigDoc= view.Getfirstdocument
Set CAREDb=s.Getdatabase("Srv1/Acme", configdoc.careLocation(0), False)
Print "Update Locked Docs, About to replicate " 
rc = caredb.Replicate("Srv2/Acme")
If rc Then
    Print "Replication from " + db.filepath + " to " + caredb.Filepath + " successful."
End If
```

ConfigDoc.CareLocation(0) = "consumer\complaintworksheet.nsf" (the relative path.) The agent is schedule and runs on the server Srv1

Comment: Suggestion re the occasional lost changes: Check both servers to see if you have multiple nsf files with the same replica ID. That can cause all sorts of weird problems.

Comment: We do have some duplicate replica ids, but only in databases completely unrelated to this project.

Comment: Okay. Good that you checked. The only other thing that comes to mind is that weird things can start to happen if the number of deletion stubs in one or both replicas gets very, very large. IIRC, you can check on that with NotesPeek, and the threshold where weird results may occur is usually somewhere over 2,000,000.

Comment: Regarding searching, the database synopsis is one way to search the design, but if there are too many design elements you may have to break it up by selecting only a subset of element types, searching, selecting another subset, etc. To get around this, I wrote myself a tool that does a DXL export of all design elements into regular documents in an NSF. I full-text indexed the NSF and am able to search that way.

Answer (score 0):

You search documents using full text search (you must create full text index beforehand). You must have reader access to all documents.

You search the design using the built-in function of the Domino Designer.

But you probably knew that.

Third possibility for your hidden text are profile documents. Write a Lotusscript agent using `GetProfileDocCollection` to find all profile docs or use an external tool like Ytria scanEZ.

Comment: I did a full-text search (and the database has a full-text index) and checked all the profile docs as well and found nothing.